# Switch UIViewController to any other UIControlller without drag and drop

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

So I know how to drag and drop different `UIControllers`, but for example the `UITabBarController` comes with additional items, `UISplitViewController` also with additional items, what if i want to convert already created `UIViewController` to `UITabBarController` or `UISplitViewController`.

I've tried editing the `XML` source, but kinda broke everything what would be the flexible way to achieve this.

Also, can i set in my `XCode` the default value for `UIControllers` simulated size to be always `FreeForm` of `width: 350, height: 450`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UISplitViewController` and `UITabBarController` are container view controllers for your `UIViewControllers`.  Those container controllers don't replace or "switch" your UIViewController to anything else.

What you do is drop a `UISplitViewController` or `UITabBarController` into your storyboard, then create (control-drag) a connection between your UIViewController and a side in the split view, or tab in the tab bar.

As to your other question, you really want to use Adaptive UI techniques (i.e. size classes), instead of trying to hardcode simulated values for your view's size.  The default view shows up as 600x600, which corresponds to wAnyXhAny.  If you need to create a different layout for a different size class, Interface Builder can handle the simulated (regular or compact) sizes for you.

Comment: For first question yeah... i found out that i can `embed in` too, so its alright. 
About second question, i just want small simulated size, because its too big and i need to scroll while designing the layout, which i believe it doesn't make a big difference if its 600x600 or other size, and every time i add Controller i need to change it to `FreeForm`, i would like somehow to make it default to `FreeForm` with specific size

Comment: Change the zoom so it fits on the screen.